# Distribute Android apps within organization

Tags: android, google-play-services, admin

I have to distribute Android apps within my organization. I have a google developer account. Below it tells to login to the admin console to enable private channel. 
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

**Problem** -it does not sign me in as Google help states that 
my.account@company.com, doesn't have an administrator but is instead managed by Google.

**Requirement** - So how can i get the administrator account.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the .apk files directly to your organization.

Either you can allow to download a signed .apk file through a web site which will launch the install procedure or you can make an app market which provides a list of .apk files and installs them automatically, as Amazon's App Shop.

Comment: Yes, I know but we want to use the Google Services. So is there any way i can get admin rights?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Google account allows you to share app locally. But we use Hockeyapp to do the same. It works great. You can even integrate it to your app and upload the crashes too. Many other features. Take a look at [this](https://www.playtestcloud.com/blog/testflight-alternatives-ios-android) to know other solutions. It supports iOS as well as Android and offers a good user experience.
But you've to pay a bit for it. CashAnalytics is free. Do small research for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have used crashlytics for this purpose in my last project.
It works great for beta distribution in development phase.
Also, it's crash reporting is excellent to guide you to the source code line causing crashes.